# Basis and Dimension of Matrices

Tags: matrices

Find a basis for and the dimension of the span of:

a. $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3   \\
   1  \\
-1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and  $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -6   \\
   -2  \\
2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

So I think that there is no basis for this because it won't be a square matrix, is this right?

Revised answer:

A= $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3 & 1 & -1   \\
   -6 & -2 & 2   \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
=$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3 & 1 & -1   \\
   0 & 0 & 0   \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

basis= $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   3 & 1 & -1   \\
  \end{array} } \right]^T$

dim=1?

b. $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2   \\
   0  \\
1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$,  $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0   \\
   -1  \\
3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ and 
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2   \\
   1  \\
-2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

So I took the transpose of each matrix and arranged them into the matrix A:

A=$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 0 & 1   \\
   0 & -1 & 3  \\
2 & 1 & 2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

I converted this to upper row echelon form:

$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2 & 0 & 1   \\
   0 & -1 & 3  \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

which gives the basis as:
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2   \\
   0  \\
1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0   \\
   -1  \\
3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

and the dim=2

c.
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1   \\
   0  \\
-1 \\
2\\
  \end{array} } \right]$ ,  $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0   \\
   1  \\
1 \\
3 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$,
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   2   \\
   -1  \\
-3 \\
1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$ and  $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1   \\
   -2  \\
1 \\
1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

A=$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & -1 & 2   \\
   0 & 1 & 1 & 3  \\
2 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & 1 & 1
  \end{array} } \right]$

reducing to row echelon form:
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 13/4   \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 7/4  \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 5/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
  \end{array} } \right]$

Well the detA=0 so does that mean there is no basis?

Revised answer:

basis= $\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 & 0 & 13/4   \\
  \end{array} } \right]^t$
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & 1 & 0 & 7/4  \\
  \end{array} } \right]^T$
$\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 & 1 & 5/4 \\
  \end{array} } \right]^T$

dim=3?

Comment: For $b$: Yes.  For $a$ and $c$: No.  It's not possible to have no basis for a vector space (except the trivial space $V=\{0\}$).

Comment: @Bye_World can you check my revised answerS?

Comment: Assuming you did the row reduction on $c$ correctly, then yes.  These are now correct.

Comment: Your (revised) method for finding a basis is correct. However, there's a slightly simpler method. Put the vectors as *columns* of a matrix (don't bother transposing) and row-reduce. The columns containing the pivots correspond to elements of a basis for the span of the columns. For example, if columns 1, 2, and 4 contain pivots, then the first, second, and fourth vectors from the *original* set (not the row-reduced matrix) form a basis.

Answer (score 1):

### Spans and bases

---

**a**
We start with $2$ vectors,
$$
\alpha =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  3 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\beta =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 -6 \\
 -2 \\
  2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Notice that $\beta = -2\alpha$.

The basis
$$
\mathcal{B} = \text{span} \left\{
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  3 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\, \right\}
$$
There is one vector. The dimension is $1$.

---

**b**
We start with $3$ vectors,
$$
\alpha =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\beta =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
 -1 \\
  3 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\gamma =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  1 \\
 -2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
We could rely upon insight to note that
$$
 \alpha - \beta = \gamma
$$
and conclude that we have $2$ linearly independent vectors, meaning the space has dimension $2$ and the basis is
$$
\mathcal{B} = \text{span} \left\{
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  0 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), \ 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
 -1 \\
  3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\, \right\}
$$

---

**c**
We start with $4$ vectors,
$$
\alpha =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  2 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\beta =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
 -2 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\gamma =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  0 \\
 -3 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\qquad
\delta =
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  3 \\
  1 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

As noted  by @Greg Martin, the quickest method is to form a matrix and use row reduction.
$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{crrc}
 1 &  0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 &  1 &  1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
 1 & -2 &  1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Clear the columns sequentially. (Note: is an example of reduced row echelon form. You could get by with the simpler row reduced form.)

*Column 1*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrr}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{crrc}
 1 &  0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 &  1 &  1 & 2 \\
 2 & -1 & -3 & 1 \\
 1 & -2 &  1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{crrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -3 \\
 0 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*Column 2*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{crrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & -1 & -1 & -3 \\
 0 & -2 & 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*Interchange last two rows*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{crrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 & 2 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 &  2 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} &  1 &  2 \\
 0 & 0 &  4 &  3 \\
 0 & 0 &  0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*Column 3*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrr}
 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{ccrr}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & -1 &  2 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} &  1 &  2 \\
 0 & 0 &  4 &  3 \\
 0 & 0 &  0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{4} \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & \frac{5}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & \frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

*Column 4*

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{4} \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & \frac{11}{4} \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & \frac{5}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & \frac{3}{4} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \boxed{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
$$

There are $4$ pivots. Therefore there are $4$ fundamental columns. Therefore each column is a basis vector. Therefore the dimension is $4$ and the basis is
$$
\mathcal{B} = \text{span} \left\{
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
  0 \\
  2 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\ 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  0 \\
  1 \\
 -1 \\
 -2 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\ 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
 -1 \\
  0 \\
 -3 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right), 
\ 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  2 \\
  3 \\
  1 \\
  1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\, \right\}
$$